# Time and Work problems:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 10 Men and 16 Women work for 6 days at the same work and the remainining work is done by 20 boys in 20 days,then find the number of days in which 12 boys can complete the whole work:

I have tried:

I have take the whole work as 1

consider  x  and 1-x be the works

x  work  completed by-> 10 Men and 16 women

1-x  work completed by -> 20 boys

with this i have formed the equation

10*16*6/x + 20*20/1-X =1

first i need to find out 1 men and 1 women work how?

How to approach this question please anyone guide me for the answer

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case men and women working together. And we have only 1 statement regarding this. So in this case its not possible to find 1 day of work of 1 men and 1 women.

If instead of days of working together their individual days are given for completing work. Then its possible.

So in above question we have insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to answer.  You need to know one more thing, like what fraction of the work was done by the men and women.  The $12$ boys will take $\frac {400}{12}$ days to do the part the $20$ boys did, but we don't know whether that is a lot or a little.